# ScalikeJdbc Multiple Insert

Tags: scala, orm, scalikejdbc

**How do we perform multiple inserts in the same transaction?**

```
  def insertData(dataList: List[Data])(implicit session: DBSession = autoSession) = {

    // todo: this is probably opening and closing a connection every time?
    dataList.foreach(data => insertData(data))
  }

  def insertData(data: Data) = withSQL {
    val t = DataTable.column
    insert.into(DataTable).namedValues(
      d.name -> data.name,
      d.title -> data.title
    )
  }.update().apply()
```

It would not be efficient to have a different transaction for every insert if these numbered in the thousands and up.

http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/operations.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your insertData method like this:

```
def insertData(data: Data)(implicit session: DBSession = AutoSession) = withSQL {
  val t = DataTable.column
  insert.into(DataTable).namedValues(
    d.name -> data.name,
    d.title -> data.title
  )
}.update().apply()
```

And then, use DB.localTx:

```
DB.localTx { implicit s =>
  dataList.foreach(data => insertData(data))
}
```

Comment: So this would perform a single transaction as opposed to mine that would create one for each insert?

Comment: Yes, accepting DBSession as an implicit parameter enables the operations to join the same transaction.

Comment: Is the `DB.localTx` block necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is if you need to run the operations within a same transaction.

Comment: Wouldn't this perform insert `dataList.length()` times?

Comment: @KazuhiroSera I'd really appreciate an answer for @kakaji question - 
Wouldn't this perform insert `dataList.length()` times?